# How would I override Laravel 5.3 sql grammar

Tags: sql-server, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

How would I set Laravel 5.3 to use VARCHAR over NVARCHAR for migrations on mssql? Is there even a way to do this?

This question also applies to SMALLDATETIME over DATETIME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a package that lets you do custom migrations without all the hassle of extending everything yourself.

https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-nomad

Once you install the package, you just change your migration to use the new `passthru` method, and you can give it the definition you want for your field.

```
// pass definition as third parameter
$table->passthru('string', 'username', 'varchar(60)');
$table->passthru('datetime', 'expires_at', 'smalldatetime');

// or use fluent definition method
$table->passthru('string', 'username')->definition('varchar(60)');
$table->passthru('datetime', 'expires_at')->definition('smalldatetime');

// if there is no defintion, it defaults to the first parameter
$table->passthru('smalldatetime', 'expires_at');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's doable, but you'll probably have to create a new database driver yourself, which involves in the creation of

```
DatabaseManager
Connection
ConnectionFactory
Schema Builder
Schema Grammar
...
```

The good part is that you probably can extend all those guys from Laravel and only change the grammar class:

```
 /**
  * Create the column definition for a string type.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
  * @return string
  */
 protected function typeString(Fluent $column)
 {
   return 'NVARCHAR ('.$column->length.')';
 }
```

An example of it in this package:

```
https://github.com/jacquestvanzuydam/laravel-firebird/tree/5.3-support/src/Firebird
```