# Add varchar column type with SQL Server using Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, nvarchar, laravel-migrations, laravel-schema-builder

I'm using Laravel 5.7 along with SQL Server 2017 and I want to generate a `varchar(50)` column called `name`.

Executing this code gives me a `nvarchar(50)` instead:

```php
Schema::create('test', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('name', 50);
});
```

How can I differentiate between creating a `varchar` or `nvarchar` field?

Comment: I've just had a look at the code and at first glance it doesn't look like there's going to be an easy way to do this, however, I did just find this answer which might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068951/how-would-i-override-laravel-5-3-sql-grammer. Essentially, to do it your self you would have to override quiet a few DB classes for  to allow use to customise the `SqlServerGrammar` class.

Comment: Updated my answer, please test and let us know. If it doesn't work I'll delete answer and wait for a better answer. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark as I don't have SQL Server to test. But basically you can just extend the `Blueprint` and `SqlServerGrammar` classes and add your own column types. Please test and let me know. :)

Create a folder called `Schemas` under the `app` folder, then create folders `Blueprints` and `Grammars` under the `Schemas` folder. Inside them, create your PHP classes:

[image: Schemas file structure]

**CustomBlueprint.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Schemas\Blueprints;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder;

class CustomBlueprint extends Blueprint
{
    public function varChar($column, $length = null)
    {
        $length = $length ? : Builder::$defaultStringLength;

        return $this->addColumn('varChar', $column, compact('length'));
    }
}
```

**CustomGrammar.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Schemas\Grammars;

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SqlServerGrammar;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent;

class CustomGrammar extends SqlServerGrammar
{
    protected function typeVarChar(Fluent $column)
    {
        return "varchar({$column->length})";
    }
}
```

**Your migration file:**

```php
public function up()
{
    DB::connection()->setSchemaGrammar(new CustomGrammar());

    $schema = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();

    $schema->blueprintResolver(function($table, $callback) {
        return new CustomBlueprint($table, $callback);
    });

    $schema->create('test', function (CustomBlueprint $table) {
        $table->string('name', 50);  // <-- nvarchar(50)
        // or
        $table->varChar('name', 50); // <-- varchar(50)
    });
}
```